# CSS Table style in Django isn't showing the table design

Tags: python, css, django, html-table, css-tables

I have a problem with one of the design in Django template, all the other designs is working fine but the table css code is not working i'm attaching a part of the css code and the relevant part from the Djnago template.

My CSS file:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    text-align: justify;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #333333;
}

table.gridtable {
    font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:11px;
    color:#333333;
    border: 1px #666666;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.gridtable th {
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid #666666;
    background-color: #dedede;
}
table.gridtable td {
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid #666666;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

form {
}

input, textarea {
    padding: 2px 5px;
    font: normal 1em "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #333333;
}
........
```

Code in Django Template:

```
.........
<div id="latest-post-wrap">
    <div id="latest-post" class="post">
        <p class="byline"></p>
{#        <p class="byline"><span>Posted on December 15th, 2007 by <a href="#">Someone</a></span></p>#}
        <h1 class="title"><a href="#">Logger</a></h1>
        <div class="entry">



{#        <table class="imagetable" border="1" style="text-align: center">#}
        <table class="gridtable">
            <tr>
                <th style="width: 100px">id</th>
                <th style="width: 100px">id Handle</th>
                <th style="width: 700px">Date</th>
                <th style="width: 100px">Name</th>
                <th style="width: 100px">Host</th>
                <th style="width: 100px">Serial Number</th>
                <th style="width: 100px">Batch Number</th>
                <th style="width: 100px">Site</th>
                <th style="width: 100px">Cavity</th>
            </tr>
            {% for handle in handles %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ handle.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ handle.idhandle }}</td>
                <td>{{ handle.createdate }}</td>
                <td>{{ handle.handlename }}</td>
                <td>{{ handle.handlehost }}</td>
                <td>{{ handle.serialnumber }}</td>
                <td>{{ handle.batchnumber }}</td>
                <td>{{ handle.site }}</td>
                <td>{{ handle.cavity }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the table style from the css is not working any ideas?
All the other styles are working ok, only the table fails to work.

**Edit1**

The current view - there is no style 
[image]

Need Style:

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a little bit more information than to state simply that it's "not working"?  In what way exactly is it not working? Have you used browser layout inspection tools to see how the browser is determining the table styles?

Comment: @Pointy NP, I've edited the title, the problem is also explained in the post.

Comment: No, it's not explained. What does it look like? What do you want it to look like?  How does the rendering differ from what you expect?

Comment: @Pointy Edit1 with the current view and the needed view i want, the problem is that there is no attention to the table style but all other styles works fine.

Comment: Well the CSS *looks* OK. Have you poked around with the browser layout inspector tools?  Make sure that the table really does have that "gridtable" class, and that the CSS is really being loaded. If the browser is not obeying the styles it must be that something unexpected is wrong, and that's really the only way to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by running `manage.py collectstatic`

Somehow it created in the Pycharm IDE 2 static files, and all mt changes where made at the wrong file.